# Webflux non-blocking to use ServerRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

We are currently using Jaxrs and access query params using URIInfo class. This is a sample:

```
@GET
@Path("/somepath")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getSomeInfo(@Context final UriInfo uriInfo)
```

We use uriInfo.getQueryParameters() to get query params. Now, we need to move our application to spring webflux (in non-reactive blocking mode). I am exploring alternative to UriInfo here but don't find a working option. There is always possibility of using @QueryParam for each individual query param but that requires too much code changes which we want to avoid at this point.

Is there any UriInfo alternative in spring webflux in non-reactive blocking mode?

I have tried the below one but getting this error "No primary or single unique constructor found for interface org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest".

```
@GetMapping(value = "/somepath",  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
ResponseEntity getSomeInfo(final ServerRequest request)
```